# testing swagger UI interface with postman

Tags: json, testing, postman, swagger-ui

I am testing swagger-UI which is a CMMS application platform.
with the available swagger UI I have integrated with post to check how the data exchange or testing the Swagger - UI.

have any one did the testing on same.

Comment: Are you talking about this : https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/ ? Could you give more details about what you are tring to achieve please ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.